# How to use libstdc++ in Mac OS X (using opencv in qt creator)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv

My system version is 10.11.6

opencv version: 2.4.13

output of gcc-v is

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I'm trying to run a project written by someone else in QT creator, in .pro file including this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libstdc++
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -stdlib=libstdc++
```

So, the code in this project uses libstdc++, and if I try to use libc++, it will output errors during building.

But even if I use libstdc++, it still has this error message:

```
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
  tvseg::cuda::cvImageShow(float*, int, int, int, char const*) in cvimageshow.o
"cv::imread(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
  tvseg::SegmentationImpl::loadImage(std::string) const in segmentationimpl.o
  tvseg::Scribbles::loadScribbleImage(std::string, cv::Mat, tvseg::Dim2) in scribbles.o
"cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
  tvseg::cuda::cvImageShow(float*, int, int, int, char const*) in cvimageshow.o
"cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
  tvseg::SegmentationImpl::saveImage(std::string, cv::Mat, bool, bool) const in segmentationimpl.o
  tvseg::Scribbles::saveScribbleImage(std::string, cv::Mat, tvseg::Dim2) const in scribbles.o
"cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
  cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>& cv::Mat::at<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3> >(int, int) in cvimageshow.o
  cv::Vec<float, 3>& cv::Mat::at<cv::Vec<float, 3> >(int, int) in cvimageshow.o
  float& cv::Mat::at<float>(int, int) in cvimageshow.o
  int& cv::Mat::at<int>(int, int) in cvimageshow.o
  bool& cv::Mat::at<bool>(int, int) in cvimageshow.o
  float* cv::Mat::ptr<float>(int, int, int) in cvimageshow.o
  cv::Vec<float, 3>& cv::Mat::at<cv::Vec<float, 3> >(int) in kmeanscpu.o
  ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [tvseg] Error 1
10:09:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project tvseg (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
10:09:05: Elapsed time: 02:00.
```

I have set QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.11

Output of lipo -info libopencv_core.dylib is

```
Non-fat file: libopencv_core.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

Output of otool -L libopencv_core.dylib is

```
libopencv_core.dylib:
    /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.13)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
    /usr/local/opt/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)
```

Here's another thing I don't know if it matters, in .pro file including this

```
LIBS += $$system(PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/pkgconfig/ pkg-config opencv --libs-only-other)
```

I've changed it to this:

```
LIBS += $$system(PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/pkgconfig/ pkg-config opencv --libs)
```

Because if using --lib-only-other, there will be more opencv functions can not be recognized. The opencv.pc file is:

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.1
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.4.13.1
Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab /usr/local/lib/libtbb.dylib
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

I think I got this error because I built opencv with libc++, but I don't know how to use libstdc++, and qt creator has this warning message:

```
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++
```

Does this mean qt creator doesn't support libstdc++, or there's some setting I can change?

---

Update: I'm using brew to install opencv, this time I 'm trying to add -stdlib=libstdc++, the final output is:

```
==> Entering interactive mode
Type `exit' to return and finalize the installation
Install to this prefix: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.1
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
Error: Empty installation
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:617:in `build'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:258:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/reinstall.rb:45:in `reinstall_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/reinstall.rb:18:in `block in reinstall'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/reinstall.rb:13:in `each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/reinstall.rb:13:in `reinstall'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:94:in `<main>'
```

Comment: With C++ you generally want to use the same compiler and runtime library throughout the entire project (including dependent libraries.) If you've built OpenCV and Qt with Clang, chances are you're using Clang's libc++ runtime library instead of GNU's libstdc++.

Comment: Is "OX" in the title a typo, or does it mean something?

Comment: @MrEricSir So how do I build OpenCV and Qt with libstdc++?